# Compare today datetime to match (First, second, third, fourth, fifth) weekday(mon, tuesday ect.) of current month

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is There any built in function in c# to compare Compare today's datetime to match like: (First, second, third, fourth, fifth) weekday(mon, tuesday ect.) of current month

or can any one please provide the custom solution for the same.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek
```

To fetch the current day of week:

```
DayOfWeek dToday = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek;
int iDay = dToday.GetHashCode(); // a number between 0-6 representing 
                                 // the days in the week
string sDayName = dToday.ToString(); // can be either Sunday, Monday .. Satruday
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can easily find out whether the day matches:

```
// Note: consider time zones...
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

if (today.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
{
    ...
}
```

and you know that the first occurrence of each day of the week will be in the range 1-7, the second will be in the range 8-14 etc. So:

```
// Check if it's the second Friday of the month...
int targetOccurrence = 2;
DayOfWeek targetDay = DayOfWeek.Friday;

DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
if (today.DayOfWeek == targetDay &&
    (today.Day + 6) / 7 == targetOccurrence)
{
    // Yes, it's the second Friday
}
```

If you want to find out whether it's before or after the second Friday of the month, that's slightly harder. Not impossible by any means, but more fiddly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DateTime.DayOfWeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek.aspx) property.

e.g.

```
if (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Someone's got a case of the Mondays!");
}
```