# How do I determine the nth day of type for a given date time in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime

## UPDATE 6/1/2013

I developed an extension method that solves this specific problem, and I have posted that code below.  I hope it helps someone out.

## Background

I have been tasked with adding functionality to an app which will allow setting up recurring meetings (exactly the same way as Outlook does).

So, for example, a user may want to set up a meeting that occurs the **first Friday of each month**, or the **last Monday of each month**, or the **second weekday** of each month, and so on.

Does a standard algorithm for this exist?  I have found plenty of partial answers, but nothing that, say, allows for a clean extension method like this:

```
  /// <summary>
        /// Accepts a date object and finds the next date given an ordinality and type.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ordinality">The ordinality (e.g. "first", "second", "last", etc.)</param>
        /// <param name="dayType">The day type (e.g. "weekday", "Monday", "day", etc)</param>
        /// <returns>A new date object</returns>
 public static DateTime GetNextDateOfType(this DateTime date, string ordinality, string dayType)
 {
 //do stuff
return newDate;
}
```

I have been working on this in fits and starts, but I keep thinking there must be something already out there.

## What I have so far:

```
     public static DateTime GetNextDateOfType(this DateTime date, string ordinality, string dayType)
        {
            var dateTest = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);
            var dateFound = false;
            var ordinal = 1;
            var targetOrdinal = ordinality.ToOrdinal();

            while (!dateFound)
            {
                //Test for type:
                switch (dayType)
                {
                    case "day":
                        if (dateTest >= date)
                        {
                            if (ordinality == "last" && dateTest == dateTest.GetLastDayOfMonth() || dateTest.Day == targetOrdinal)
                            {
                                dateFound = true;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case "weekday":
                        if (dateTest >= date && dateTest.IsWeekDay())
                        {
                            if (targetOrdinal == ordinal)
                            {
                                dateFound = true;
                            }
                            ordinal++;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "weekend day":
                        if (dateTest >= date && !dateTest.IsWeekDay())
                        {
                            dateFound = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        if (dateTest >= date && dateTest.DayOfWeek == HelperMethods.GetDayOfWeekFromString(dayType))
                        {
                            dateFound = true;
                        }
                        break;
                }
   
                dateTest = dateTest.AddDays(1);

            }

            return dateTest;
        }

   public static DateTime GetLastDayOfMonth(this DateTime date)
        {
            return new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month));
        }

        public static int ToOrdinal(this string ordinal)
        {
            var result = 0;
            switch (ordinal.ToLower())
            {
                case "first":
                    result = 1;
                    break;
                case "second":
                    result = 2;
                    break;
                case "third":
                    result = 3;
                    break;
                case "fourth":
                    result = 4;
                    break;
                case "fifth":
                    result = 5;
                    break;
                default:
                    result = -1;
                    break;
            }
            return result;
        }

        public static bool IsWeekDay(this DateTime date)
        {
            var weekdays = new List<DayOfWeek>
                {
                    DayOfWeek.Monday,
                    DayOfWeek.Tuesday,
                    DayOfWeek.Wednesday,
                    DayOfWeek.Thursday,
                    DayOfWeek.Friday
                };

            return weekdays.Contains(date.DayOfWeek);
        }

        public static List<DateTime> GetWeeks(this DateTime month, DayOfWeek startOfWeek)
        {
            var firstOfMonth = new DateTime(month.Year, month.Month, 1);
            var daysToAdd = ((Int32)startOfWeek - (Int32)month.DayOfWeek) % 7;
            var firstStartOfWeek = firstOfMonth.AddDays(daysToAdd);

            var current = firstStartOfWeek;
            var weeks = new List<DateTime>();
            while (current.Month == month.Month)
            {
                weeks.Add(current);
                current = current.AddDays(7);
            }

            return weeks;
        }

        public static int GetWeekOfMonth(this DateTime date)
        {
            var beginningOfMonth = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);

            while (date.Date.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek != CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek)
                date = date.AddDays(1);

            return (int)Math.Truncate((double)date.Subtract(beginningOfMonth).TotalDays / 7f) + 1;
        }
```

Comment: Do you only ever care about the month level? Ex, would you ever be interested in the 1st Monday of the Quarter? Or, Friday of every week?

Comment: @MikeP--I think that what you are suggesting would be very useful, though I don't have a current need for it.  Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET

Comment: @Sorceri - that's for intervals.  It doesn't cover this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare today datetime to match (First, second, third, fourth, fifth) weekday(mon, tuesday ect.) of current month](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378257/compare-today-datetime-to-match-first-second-third-fourth-fifth-weekdaymo)

Comment: And see [Jon Skeet's Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9378324/634824) in that post.

Comment: Here's [another dup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288513/how-do-i-determine-if-a-given-date-is-the-nth-weekday-of-the-month)

Comment: @MattJohnson--While I appreciate your effort in leaving comments, NONE of your "duplicate" links are duplicates.  In fact, even the Jon Skeet answer that you pointed out speaks to my question in it's last sentence and notes that it involves a different, harder solution.  While I am at it, I think that the term "possible duplicate" is silly.  Something either is or isn't a duplicate.  Saying "possible duplicate" to me translates to, "I dunno it might be a duplicate but it would require that I actually take the time to think about what I am posting to be sure".  We should avoid that that.

Comment: CONTINUED--The problem with guys saying "possible duplicate" and voting to close is that the ACTUAL QUESTION never gets answered and therefore can't help the next guy that faces the problem.

Comment: Any reason for why the ordinal parameter is not an enum?

Comment: No particular reason.  Why?

Comment: It just seems to be a bit fragile to send in a string.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen-- I don't see why, can you please help me understand?  How would an `enum` work here?  Or, if you would like to edit the code and add it as your own answer, I would be happy to award you the points.

Comment: My point is: what if I pass in "Easter" here? There's no end to "valid" string values that this method will "accept" without it actually meaning anything. An enum would make it clear to whoever is calling the method what the possible input values to the combinations you would actually be able to handle are.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen--Ahhhh, I see.  Yes, good point.  Though, it would be pretty awesome if you could pass in a holiday like "Easter" and have it return the correct date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling with this for a while, here is the solution I came up with.  It is an extension method (with other referenced extension methods beneath it).  This is not my most elegant code, but it works.  I will update the code later if I streamline it in my own environment.

Simple usage example for getting the *second* *Monday* of a month closest to the passed-in date:

```
var newDate= someDate.GetNextDateOfType("second", "Monday");
```

## The code:

```
    public static DateTime GetNextDateOfType(this DateTime date, string ordinality, string dayType)
            {
                var targetOrdinal = ordinality.ToOrdinal();
                var dateTest = (targetOrdinal > -1) ? new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1) : date.GetLastDayOfMonth();
                var dateFound = false;
                var ordinal = 1;
                var ordinalReset = false;

                if (targetOrdinal > -1) //All cases EXCEPT "last"
                {
                    while (!dateFound)
                    {
                        if (dateTest.Month > date.Month && !ordinalReset)
                        {
                            ordinal = 1;
                            ordinalReset = true;
                        }

                        //Test for type:
                        switch (dayType)
                        {
                            case "day":
                                if (dateTest >= date)
                                {
                                    if (dateTest.Day == targetOrdinal)
                                    {
                                        dateFound = true;
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                            case "weekday":
                                if (dateTest >= date && dateTest.IsWeekDay())
                                {
                                    if (targetOrdinal == ordinal)
                                    {
                                        dateFound = true;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (dateTest.IsWeekDay())
                                {
                                    ordinal++;
                                }

                                break;
                            case "weekend day":
                                if (dateTest >= date && !dateTest.IsWeekDay())
                                {
                                    if (targetOrdinal == ordinal)
                                    {
                                        dateFound = true;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (!dateTest.IsWeekDay())
                                {
                                    ordinal++;
                                }

                                break;
                            default:
                                if (dateTest >= date && dateTest.DayOfWeek == HelperMethods.GetDayOfWeekFromString(dayType))
                                {
                                    if (targetOrdinal == ordinal)
                                    {
                                        dateFound = true;
                                    }
                                }

                                if (dateTest.DayOfWeek == HelperMethods.GetDayOfWeekFromString(dayType))
                                {
                                    ordinal++;
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                        dateTest = (dateFound) ? dateTest : dateTest.AddDays(1);
                    }
                }
                else //for "last"
                {
                    while (!dateFound)
                    {
                        if (dateTest <= date && !ordinalReset)
                        {
                            dateTest = date.GetLastDayOfMonth().AddMonths(1);
                            ordinalReset = true;
                        }

                        //Test for type:
                        switch (dayType)
                        {
                            case "day":
                                dateFound = true;
                                break;
                            case "weekday":
                                if (dateTest.IsWeekDay())
                                {
                                        dateFound = true;
                                }

                                break;
                            case "weekend day":
                                if (!dateTest.IsWeekDay())
                                {
                                    dateFound = true;
                                }
                                break;
                            default:
                                if (dateTest.DayOfWeek == HelperMethods.GetDayOfWeekFromString(dayType))
                                {
                                    dateFound = true;
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                        dateTest = (dateFound) ? dateTest : dateTest.AddDays(-1);
                    }
                }
                return dateTest;
            }

            public static DateTime GetLastDayOfMonth(this DateTime date)
            {
                return new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month));
            }

            public static int ToOrdinal(this string ordinal)
            {
                var result = 0;
                switch (ordinal.ToLower())
                {
                    case "first":
                        result = 1;
                        break;
                    case "second":
                        result = 2;
                        break;
                    case "third":
                        result = 3;
                        break;
                    case "fourth":
                        result = 4;
                        break;
                    case "fifth":
                        result = 5;
                        break;
                    default:
                        result = -1;
                        break;
                }
                return result;
            }

            public static bool IsWeekDay(this DateTime date)
            {
                var weekdays = new List<DayOfWeek>
                    {
                        DayOfWeek.Monday,
                        DayOfWeek.Tuesday,
                        DayOfWeek.Wednesday,
                        DayOfWeek.Thursday,
                        DayOfWeek.Friday
                    };

                return weekdays.Contains(date.DayOfWeek);
            }

            public static List<DateTime> GetWeeks(this DateTime month, DayOfWeek startOfWeek)
            {
                var firstOfMonth = new DateTime(month.Year, month.Month, 1);
                var daysToAdd = ((Int32)startOfWeek - (Int32)month.DayOfWeek) % 7;
                var firstStartOfWeek = firstOfMonth.AddDays(daysToAdd);

                var current = firstStartOfWeek;
                var weeks = new List<DateTime>();
                while (current.Month == month.Month)
                {
                    weeks.Add(current);
                    current = current.AddDays(7);
                }

                return weeks;
            }

            public static int GetWeekOfMonth(this DateTime date)
            {
                var beginningOfMonth = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1);

                while (date.Date.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek != CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek)
                    date = date.AddDays(1);

                return (int)Math.Truncate((double)date.Subtract(beginningOfMonth).TotalDays / 7f) + 1;
            }


 public static DayOfWeek GetDayOfWeekFromString(string day)
        {
            var dow = DayOfWeek.Sunday;
            switch (day)
            {
                case "Sunday":
                    dow = DayOfWeek.Sunday;
                    break;
                case "Monday":
                    dow = DayOfWeek.Monday;
                    break;
                case "Tuesday":
                    dow = DayOfWeek.Tuesday;
                    break;
                case "Wednesday":
                    dow = DayOfWeek.Wednesday;
                    break;
                case "Thursday":
                    dow = DayOfWeek.Thursday;
                    break;
                case "Friday":
                    dow = DayOfWeek.Friday;
                    break;
                case "Saturday":
                    dow = DayOfWeek.Saturday;
                    break;
            }

            return dow;
        }
```

Comment: I see what you were after now.  Yes this is more complex than the answers I posted as duplicates.  But this is in some serious need of refactoring.  I will have some time in the next day or two to post an optimized way of doing this.  The biggest issue I see in the current code are all the while loops. You can probably do better with some math.  Loops tests can be slow. Also, a lot of those string to enum conversions seem unnecessary.  Do you know about `Enum.Parse()`?  And is there any real reason you need strings at all?  It's usually best to keep strings out of something like this.

Comment: @MattJohnson--Thanks Matt.  Agreed that this needs refactoring and no, there is no explicit need for the strings.  I was simply working fast to beat a deadline.  Any improvement you can offer up will be appreciated by many, I am sure, as there just wasn't anything out there to fill this particular void.  Thanks again.